# dplyr 0.7.5 on Linux Centos 7, select function does not work

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I managed to installed the dplyr 0.7.5 on Linux Centos using the github development release:

```
 devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
```

oh, man, it is not easy. Had to update a myriad of packages before getting this new dplyr installed.

Before dplyr 0.7.5, I was using 0.5.0. However version 0.5.0 does not support "sparklyr", which I use to read parquet file from disk and convert into spark data frame.  Anyways, after I installed dplyr 0.7.5, many old dplyr codes broke. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1, 2, 3), B=c('a', 'b', 'c'))
a <- df %>% dplyr::select(A)
```

---- This used to work in dplyr 0.5.0, but I kept getting error in dplyr 0.7.5:

> Error: Expect a list of quosures.

--- looks like the support of Non-Standard-Evaluation is all broken.

Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you include the output of `sessionInfo()`? You can [edit] your question to insert it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently running CentOS 7.4.1708 and cannot replicate the problem you describe.

Use `packrat` to create a clean environment and check if the problem is really due to your version of dplyr. Then you can add parts from your scripts and narrow down when the problem starts cropping up.

Do the following to create a clean test environment:

```
# Create a test folder
dir.create("test")
setwd("test")
# packrat creates a private package library, so you are sure about your package versions
if(!require(packrat)) install.packages("packrat")
packrat::init()
# Install the development version of dplyr
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
# Test your example
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(A=c(1, 2, 3), B=c('a', 'b', 'c'))
a <- df %>% dplyr::select(A)
```

(Session info:)

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /opt/Bio/R/3.4.3/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /opt/Bio/R/3.4.3/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.7.5.9000

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16     packrat_0.4.9-1  digest_0.6.15    withr_2.1.2     
 [5] assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.2.2         magrittr_1.5     git2r_0.21.0    
 [9] pillar_1.2.2     httr_1.3.1       rlang_0.2.0      curl_3.2        
[13] bindrcpp_0.2.2   devtools_1.13.5  tools_3.4.3      glue_1.2.0      
[17] purrr_0.2.4      compiler_3.4.3   pkgconfig_2.0.1  memoise_1.1.0   
[21] tidyselect_0.2.4 bindr_0.1.1      tibble_1.4.2
```